# What are other methods for a c++ compile error about __attribute__((__packed__))?

Tags: c++, g++

when I compiled the following code:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct TupleHeader {
    timeval     tuple_stime; // 34..37
}__attribute__((__packed__));

 void set_value(timeval& stime){ 
}

int main(){
    TupleHeader tuple;
    set_value(tuple.tuple_stime);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the error under `g++-3.4.2` and `g++-4.8.3`:

```
attribute-1.cc: In function `int main()':
attribute-1.cc:13: error: cannot bind packed field `tuple.TupleHeader::tuple_stime' to `timeval&'
```

After I defined `timeval` myself as follows and changed all `timevals` in the above code into `timeval2`:

```
struct timeval2
{
  __time_t tv_sec;
  __suseconds_t tv_usec;
}__attribute__((__packed__));
```

the error is gone, but I don't want to define a struct that already exists in `<bits/time.h>` . What are other methods to correct this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Write code that does not depend on structure padding (or lack of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want. If you want the inner timeval to be tight-packed as well, repeating the struct declaration is pretty much your only option: The default-packed struct and the tight-packed structs have members with the same names, but the difference in packing makes them fundamentally different types. (FWIW, since you're clearly trying to save space anyway, you can take this opportunity to make it a bitfield, and allot `tv_usec` only twenty bits!)

If, on the other hand, you don't care about there being padding within the timeval -- only between it and the other structs -- your other option is to declare it as `char tuple_stime[sizeof(timeval)]` instead, and cast it as necessary. (Don't forget about aliasing concerns.)

Comment: And alignment concerns.

Comment: Like Sneftel mentioned, the packed attribute affects the fundamental type, more detailed description [here.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36566)