# How to correct a error about g++'s reference parameter with __attribute__((__packed__)) struct's member?

Tags: c++, struct

After I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25669751/1054800), I further tried simpler member variable in a packed struct, and I got the same error. I am confused!

When compiling the following code:

```
struct TupleHeader {
  int  tuple_stime; 
}__attribute__((__packed__));

void set_value(int& stime){
}

int main(){
    TupleHeader tuple;
    set_value(tuple.tuple_stime);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the error:

```
[borealis@localhost cpp-program]$ g++ attribute-1.cc 
attribute-1.cc: In function `int main()':
attribute-1.cc:13: error: cannot bind packed field `tuple.TupleHeader::tuple_stime' to `int&'
```

After I changed the function definition `set_value(int& stime)` into `set_value(int stime)`, the error is gone. I want to ask whether there are other methods except modifying `set_value(int& stime)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution isn't even a valid one, as far as I can tell, because by applying it you *completely* break your program.

The best bet is to send a reference to the whole `TupleHeader`, and access `.tuple_stime` within `set_value`… after giving it a descriptive name, of course.

Answer (score 2):

GCC doesn't seem to complain with `#pragma pack`

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct TupleHeader {
  int  tuple_stime; 
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Another option is a cast

```
set_value(reinterpret_cast<int&>(tuple.tuple_stime));
```

Either is potentially unsafe depending on your platform alignment requirements (i.e. you probably shouldn't be doing this in the first place).

Comment: The cast is definitely inadvisable.